# Xcode 9 Swift 4 Complex JSON decoding

Tags: json, xcode9, swift4.2

I am working with API data that returns JSON data that is hard to decode.  The api call is for a batch of stock quotations.  When a single quotation (not batch) is called, the result is easily decoded JSON using a simple struct.  However, in batch mode the single quote version is grouped within two more levels that I can not decode.  In the interest of making this easy to read I will just paste the initial pieces of the data in order to illustrate the issue.

The single quote JSON:

```
{"symbol":"AAPL","companyName":"Apple Inc.","primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
```

So, that's easy... key, value pairs from the start but in batch mode this becomes:

```
{"AAPL":{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","companyName":"Apple Inc.","primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
```

and then later in that same result would be a second or third or more quote, eg.

```
}},"FB":{"quote":{"symbol":"FB","companyName":"Facebook Inc.","primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
```

So at the highest level it is not a key but is instead a value.  And the second level is a metadata type placeholder for quote (because you can also request other subelement arrays like company, charts, etc.) I can't think of how to handle the outer grouping(s) especially the stock symbols AAPL and FB ... as the outermost elements.  Any thoughts anyone?

I have started down the path of JSONSerialization which produces a string that I also cannot get into a usable form.

For this I am using:

```
    let tkrs = "C,DFS"

    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "api.iextrading.com" 
    components.path = "/1.0/stock/market/batch"
    let queryItemSymbols = URLQueryItem(name: "symbols", value: "\(tkrs)")
    let queryItemTypes = URLQueryItem(name: "types", value: "quote")
    components.queryItems = [queryItemSymbols,queryItemTypes]
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: components.url!) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
            print(json)
```

which produces:

```
["C": {
quote =     {
    avgTotalVolume = 17386485;
    calculationPrice = tops;
    change = "1.155";
    changePercent = "0.0181";
    close = "63.8";
    closeTime = 1540411451191;
    companyName = "Citigroup Inc.";
```

and there is more data but I'm clipping it short.

The api url's are:

single quote example:

```
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/quote
```

batch quote example:

```
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb&types=quote
```

The struct I have used successfully for the single quote works nicely with a simple line of code:

```
let quote = try JSONDecoder().decode(Quote.self,from: data)
```

where Quote is a struct:

```
struct Quote: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let companyName: String
    let primaryExchange: String
    let sector: String
    let calculationPrice: String
    let open: Double
    let openTime: Int
    let close: Double
    let closeTime: Int
    let high: Double
    let low: Double
    let latestPrice: Double
    let latestSource: String
    let latestTime: String
    let latestUpdate: Int
    let latestVolume: Double
    let iexRealtimePrice: Double?
    let iexRealtimeSize: Double?
    let iexLastUpdated: Int?
    let delayedPrice: Double
    let delayedPriceTime: Int
    let extendedPrice: Double
    let extendedChange: Double
    let extendedChangePercent: Double
    let extendedPriceTime: Int
    let previousClose: Double
    let change: Double
    let changePercent: Double
    let iexMarketPercent: Double?
    let iexVolume: Double?
    let avgTotalVolume: Double
    let iexBidPrice: Double?
    let iexBidSize: Double?
    let iexAskPrice: Double?
    let iexAskSize: Double?
    let marketCap: Double
    let peRatio: Double?
    let week52High: Double
    let week52Low: Double
    let ytdChange: Double
}
```

Edit: based on answer provided

Working in a playground this works well with the batch data:

```
func getPrices(){
    let tkrs = "AAPL,FB,C,DFS,MSFT,ATVI"
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "api.iextrading.com" ///1.0/stock/market/batch
    components.path = "/1.0/stock/market/batch"
    let queryItemSymbols = URLQueryItem(name: "symbols", value: "\(tkrs)")
    let queryItemTypes = URLQueryItem(name: "types", value: "quote")
    components.queryItems = [queryItemSymbols,queryItemTypes]
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: components.url!)
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String: Quote]].self,from: data)
        let tickers = ["AAPL","FB","C","DFS","MSFT","ATVI"]
        for tk in tickers {
            let quote = response[tk]
            let price = quote!["quote"]
            print("\(price!.symbol) \(price!.latestPrice)")
        }
    } catch let jsonErr { print("Error decoding json:",jsonErr)}
}
```

But this solves my initial problem of getting a response back from a URLSession for just a single quote.  I can now run through an array of stock symbols and update the latest price for each item with this function.

```
func getPrice(ticker: String) -> Double {
    var price = 0.0
    let urlString = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/\(ticker)/quote"
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Quote.self,from: data)
        price = response.latestPrice
    } catch let jsonErr { print("Error decoding JSON:",jsonErr)}
    return price
}
```

So, I am iterating through an array of open stock trades and setting the price like this...

```
opentrades[rn].trCurPrice = getPrice(ticker: opentrades[rn].trTicker)
```

And it works great in my application.  Although I am a little worried about how it will workout during times of high latency.  I realize I need some error control and will work to integrate that going forward.

Edit/Update:  Based on feedback here is the approach I'm taking.

Created a class to be a delegate that accepts an array of open trades and updates the prices.

```
import Foundation

protocol BatchQuoteManagerDelegate {
    func didLoadBatchQuote()
}

class BatchQuoteManager {
    var openPositions = [OpenTradeDur]()
    var delegate: BatchQuoteManagerDelegate? = nil
    func getBatchQuote(tickers: [OpenTradeDur]) {
        var tkrs = ""
        for tk in tickers {
            tkrs = tkrs + "\(tk.trTicker),"
        }
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "api.iextrading.com"
        components.path = "/1.0/stock/market/batch"
        let queryItemSymbols = URLQueryItem(name: "symbols", value: "\(tkrs)")
        let queryItemTypes = URLQueryItem(name: "types", value: "quote")
        components.queryItems = [queryItemSymbols,queryItemTypes]
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: components.url!) {(data,response,error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String: Quote]].self,from: data)
            for i in 0..<tickers.count {
                let quote = response[tickers[i].trTicker]
                let price = quote!["quote"]
                tickers[i].trCurPrice = price!.latestPrice
            }
            self.openPositions = tickers
            if let delegate = self.delegate {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    delegate.didLoadBatchQuote()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I then extend my ViewController with `BatchQuoteManagerDelegate`, implement the `func didLoadBatchQuote()` method where I get the updated prices via the `BatchQuoteManager.openPositions` array.  I just needed to define `let batchQuoteManager = BatchQuoteManager()`  in my ViewController and within `viewDidLoad()` include the statement `batchQuoteManager.delegate = self`.  Once I know that all the necessary data has been loaded into my ViewController I call the function to get prices (at the end of `viewDidLoad()`) with `batchQuoteManager.getBatchQuote(tickers: opentrades)`

And that's it.  It is working very nicely so far.

Comment: try this `try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String: Quote]].self,from: data)`

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` type conditionally conforms to `Decodable` if its associated `KeyType` and `ValueType` conform to `Decodable`. You can decode the whole `Dictionary`.

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String: Quote]].self,from: data)
let apple = response["AAPL"]
let appleQuote = apple["quote"]
```

Try this gist in a playground

https://gist.github.com/caquant/eeee66b7b8df447c4ea06b8ab8c1116a

Edit: Here is a quick example with `URLSession`

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard  let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String: Quote]].self,from: data)
    let apple = response["FB"]
    let appleQuote = apple!["quote"]
    print(appleQuote!)
}

dataTask.resume()
```

Note: The gist was also updated.

Comment: Thank you quant24.  That works brilliantly.  So well that I can actually abandon the batch method and work with a single quote request but I do not quite understand why.  The github example you provided does not make use of a URLSession.   I was able to write a func that returns the price for a single stock immediately.  I can then run through an array of stocks and update the prices on each of them.  But with a URLSession and task.resume() scenario none of that worked for me.  How is this working without all that?

Comment: @Mooky Oh, sorry I was just trying to do a fast example using a synchronous connection on the main thread (you probably don't want to do that). With `NSURLSession` you want to use the data argument from the `closure`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes that works well.  I have gone back to the session approach.  Editing my post with how I'm doing it.